# Contar varias filas de la misma columna en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

| Id | local_name | estado | persona |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Local_1 | Votado | Juan |
| 1 | Local_1 | Votado | José |
| 1 | Local_1 | Votado | María |
| 2 | Local_2 | Votado | Pedro |
| 2 | local_2 | Votado | Roberto |

Tengo una tabla llamada votación, donde cada persona esta asignada a un local y va a votar, mi pregunta es, existe algún modo de contar cuantos votos hubo en cada local, por separado pero sin tener que escribir la id del local o el hombre del local, ya que tengo esta consulta pero a la fuerza me pide escribir cada local, cabe aclarar que la cantidad de locales es indefinida, puede ser 5 o puede ser 200

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(IF(local_name = 'Local_1', 1, 0)) contlocal1,
    SUM(IF(local_name = 'Local_2', 1, 0)) contlocal2
FROM
    votacion
WHERE
    estado = 'Votado';
```

Esto me da como resultado:

| contlocal1 | contlocal2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |

existe un modo en el que no tenga que escribir cada local y obtener el mismo resultado?

Answer (score 0):

Si que existe, puedes agrupar con [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) por local_name, y contar los votos si el estado es 'votado':

```
SELECT
    local_name,
    count(*) AS votos
FROM
    votacion
WHERE
    estado = 'Votado'
GROUP BY local_name
```